# Concurrent access to a DataSource of jasperServer

Tags: concurrency, jasperserver

I am trying to invoke a report using rest V2 API but I have a problem regarding the dataSource concurrency access. I will just provide the following scenario where application 1 requested the report then application 2 requested the same report.

**Application 1 :**

```
Retrieve the version of report 1 

Patch the data source of the report 1 with dataSource1

Sleep 10 seconds

Download  the report 1
```

**Application 2 :**

```
Retrieve the version of report 1

Patch the data source of the report 1 with dataSource2

Download the report 2
```

Because the application 1 pauses  10 seconds, application 2 patched the report with data source 2 and the result of this is that application 1 gets the results that are provided by the dataSource 2.

I want any suggestion to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Both reports should get their own data source if there are two use cases (hence: two reports/two states of data) involved.

Comment: thanks, @tobi6 i think this solve the issue. However, I have solved the issue differently by creating a temporary copy of the report.